# memory_profiler %mprun with imported function works but don't display the profiler as a table, how to fix that?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, memory-profiling

I'm studying memory_profiler with a function i made just for practice purposes, and the memory_profiler doesn't display the memory usage as a table. The function file (FuncExamples.py) is in the same folder as the jupyter notebook.

The code is running inside vscode with the jupyter notebook extension. If i run in an anaconda terminal it just displays normally as a table.
Code:

```
%load_ext memory_profiler
from funcExamples import senha

%mprun -f senha senha()
```

How the memory usage is displayed:

```
The memory_profiler extension is already loaded. To reload it, use:
  %reload_ext memory_profiler

Filename: d:\Tech\funcExamples.py Line # Mem usage Increment Occurences Line Contents ============================================================ 1 43.7 MiB 43.7 MiB 1 def senha(): 2 43.7 MiB 0.0 MiB 1 import random 3 4 43.7 MiB 0.0 MiB 1 letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' 5 43.7 MiB 0.0 MiB 1 symbols='!@#$%&*' 6 43.7 MiB 0.0 MiB 1 numbers=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'] 7 43.7 MiB 0.0 MiB 1 a=list(letters) 8 43.7 MiB 0.0 MiB 1 b=list(symbols) 9 43.7 MiB 0.0 MiB 1 x=random.choices(a,k=8) 10 43.7 MiB 0.0 MiB 1 y=random.choices(b,k=2) 11 43.7 MiB 0.0 MiB 1 z=random.choices(numbers,k=4) 12 43.7 MiB 0.0 MiB 1 soma_lists=x+y+z 13 43.7 MiB 0.0 MiB 1 random.shuffle(soma_lists) 14 43.7 MiB 0.0 MiB 1 senha=''.join(soma_lists) 15 43.7 MiB 0.0 MiB 1 return senha
```

Line_profiler (that has the same way to show the profiler) works fine. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The message you are getting is not an error but rather telling you that the extension you are trying to use is already loaded "%load_ext memory_profiler." You could get rid of this message by separating the line: %load_ext memory_profiler into its own cell in your jupyter notebook and then each time you want to run the memory profiler tool, restart your jupyter notebook kernel and rerun your code.